# Group and show items of same type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a listView of items and these items are to be grouped together based on a class and shown with boxes.

Suppose I have 5 items with:

```
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="1"></div>
<div class="2"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
<div class="3"></div>
```

[image]

Need boxes just like this to show the similar items.

Once we add a new item to the ViewModel with a class of 1, the box needs to add the new item to the first box.

Can anyone help me out in how to group the items which have same class and how do we show a box with CSS on the items which have same class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a bit of jQuery to wrap all elements with matching class names with a wrapper:

```
var elems = $('div').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
});
$.unique(elems).each(function(i, el) {
    $('.'+el).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

You can then just apply your CSS to the .wrapper class (or name it whatever you want).

Here is a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvGbLy).

Comment: Cool, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can add an extra element inside the divs, then you could always fake it with something like [this](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/RxPWgm). Could probably achieve a similar effect using psuedo elements as well. Don't forget you can also create [borders using drop shadows](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/), depending on what you need :)

**CSS**

```
* {
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
[class^="class"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  background: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.class1 {
  background: green;
}

.class3 {
  background: purple;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="class1"><div class="inner">1</div></div>
<div class="class1"><div class="inner">1</div></div>
<div class="class2"><div class="inner">2</div></div>
<div class="class3"><div class="inner">3</div></div>
<div class="class3"><div class="inner">3</div></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/RxPWgm)